# Ads from Admob won't show in my app

Tags: android, ads

I published a free app on the Google Play Store yesterday and I added ads to the app but the app doesn't show the ads.
I'm using Admob to generate the ads but even though the emulator displayed the example ads, in the final version on the Play Store the ads won't show up.

I tried few solutions from google (both google search and google developer) and the ads still not showing up.

Anyone knows what shoud I do?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: You added ads to an app that you purchased from the Google Play Store and republished it on the Google Play Store?

Comment: did your admob show up when you used test id?

Comment: No i developed my own app :/
Yes when i tested it only on the emulator i saw the test ads

Answer (score 1):

If they are your first ads and it has only been a couple of days since your publish, then it is normal not to see them yet. Wait a couple more days and they should show up in your app, if you were able to see the example ones in the emulator.

Comment: OK thank you, but the test ads i was able to see only on the emulator and not the actual device, is that ok?

Comment: yes i also experienced inconsistency in that aspect. you may want to double check your keys from admob either way